# Does $\{π+1/n :\, n \in \Bbb N\}$ have an infimum?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Does the set
$$A=\left\{π+\frac1n :\, n \in \Bbb N\right\}$$
have infimum?

I assume $\pi$ is the infimum, because when $n$ tends to infinity the smallest possible element of $A$ tends to $\pi$, does not hit the $\pi$. I do not know if I am right, or if I am right, how should prove what the infimum of this set is?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show some work. This follows directly from the definition of $\inf$.

Comment: Incidentally, $\pi$ is also the infimum of $A \cup \{\pi\}$.  It is not necessary that the set not "hit" $\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

Your set contains the number $\pi+\frac1{43}$, so it is not empty.

All of its elements are positive, so it is bounded below by $0$.

A nonempty set of reals that is bounded below always has an infimum. Case closed.

Comment: I don't think the question was about the existence of the infimum, but it rather was about **what** the infimum is...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Both the title and the first part of the body ask about the existence of the infimum, so I think the answer is apposite, but it is also helpful to show that $\pi$ is indeed the infimum, so I've added my answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio: As Brian says, it looks to me like the OP's end goal is to find out just whether an infimum exists. The point of _this_ answer is to point out in a vivid way that it _is possible_ to known (and prove) that the set has an infimum without knowing what that infimum _is_ -- since the question makes me suspect he was not fully aware of that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I agree, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the thoughts from Henning and José.

$\pi < \pi+\frac1n$ for any natural $n$, so $\pi$ is a lower bound.

Next, let $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $m = 1 + \left\lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \right\rceil$.  $m$ is a natural number, so $\pi + \frac1m$ is in the set, but $\pi + \frac1m < \pi + \varepsilon$, so $\pi + \varepsilon$ is not a lower bound of the set.

Therefore $\pi$ is the infimum of the set.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Since $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\pi\leqslant\pi+\frac1n$, $\pi$ is a lower bound of $A$. And, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi+\frac1n=\pi$, $\pi=\inf A$.

Comment: Also $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}n=0\;$ yet $\;0\;$ is *not* the infimum of the sequence $\;\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}n\right\}\;$ . Either some monotony argument must be used or else directly by the definition of infimum...using that limit there, yes.